# Emberjs-1.0.0 app - Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'applyPartial'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, ruby-on-rails-4, ember-data, ember-router

I am using the latest canary build of  Emberjs-1.0.0 and Ember-data 1.0.0-beta-2 on a **rails-4** app. When I use this **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WqRZQ/)** with the exact code in emberjs app from the rails app, no error is thrown, but when I start the rails app and try to go to the index page of the ember-app, it will throw the error **Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'applyPartial'**

Nothing else is mentioned making it hard to debug or pin down the exact issue. I have removed turbo-links, so it is not a factor here.

Based on the uncaught exception thrown, it boils down to this line in emberjs
https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/8624e8513a8db0294856cd3f559127dd7a7820b3/packages/ember-runtime/lib/system/core_object.js#L147

```
Class.PrototypeMixin.applyPartial(Class.prototype);
```

**This screenshots are based on the emberjs-app not loading from within a rails-4 app**

[image]

**A screenshot of the callstack, here is shows superclass as Store, other times it shows unknownMixin**
[image]

@Jeremy here is the full list of  tags that appear in my page after rendering. I got this via **view page source** I have ran **rake tmp:clear rake assets:clean**, but the problem is still there

```
   <script src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1"></script>
   <script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1"></script>
   <script src="/assets/handlebars.js?body=1"></script>
   <script src="/assets/ember.js?body=1"></script>
   <script src="/assets/ember-data.js?body=1"></script>
   <script src="/assets/application.js?body=1"></script>
   <script src="/assets/store.js?body=1"></script>
   <script src="/assets/models/users.js?body=1"></script>
   <script src="/assets/controllers/application_controller.js?body=1"></script>
   <script src="/assets/controllers/login_controller.js?body=1"></script>
   <script src="/assets/controllers/signup_controller.js?body=1"></script>
   <script src="/assets/controllers/user_controller.js?body=1"></script>
   <script src="/assets/controllers/user_edit_controller.js?body=1"></script>
   <script src="/assets/controllers/users_controller.js?body=1"></script>
   <script src="/assets/templates/application.js?body=1"></script>
   <script src="/assets/templates/index.js?body=1"></script>
   <script src="/assets/templates/login.js?body=1"></script>
   <script src="/assets/templates/signup.js?body=1"></script>
   <script src="/assets/templates/user.js?body=1"></script>
   <script src="/assets/templates/user/edit.js?body=1"></script>
   <script src="/assets/templates/user/index.js?body=1"></script>
   <script src="/assets/templates/users.js?body=1"></script>
   <script src="/assets/templates/users/index.js?body=1"></script>
   <script src="/assets/router.js?body=1"></script>
   <script src="/assets/routes/application_route.js?body=1"></script>
   <script src="/assets/routes/authenticated_route.js?body=1"></script>
   <script src="/assets/routes/login_route.js?body=1"></script>
   <script src="/assets/routes/signup_route.js?body=1"></script>
   <script src="/assets/routes/user/edit_route.js?body=1"></script>
   <script src="/assets/routes/user/index_route.js?body=1"></script>
   <script src="/assets/routes/user_route.js?body=1"></script>
   <script src="/assets/routes/users/index_route.js?body=1"></script>
   <script src="/assets/routes/users_route.js?body=1"></script>
   <script src="/assets/app.js?body=1"></script>
   <script src="/assets/lib/development/ember-data.js?body=1"></script>
  <script src="/assets/lib/development/ember.js?body=1"></script>
  <script src="/assets/lib/production/ember-data.js?body=1"></script>
  <script src="/assets/lib/production/ember.js?body=1"></script>
  <script src="/assets/note_books.js?body=1"></script>
  <script src="/assets/notes.js?body=1"></script>
```

Comment: Are you using some build tools, like: ember-app-kit, ember-tools etc? Can you show what is the structure of the object Class.PrototypeMixin, before the error is throwed. The output of console.log(Class.PrototypeMixin) would help

Comment: Thanks and no I am not using any build tools. This emberjs downloaded from **http://emberjs.com/builds/** the **Class.PrototypeMixin** is a emberjs framework. I system is down but when it comes back I will try do see if I can log it to console. In the mean-time, there is a link in the question to the source for **Class.PrototypeMixin**

Comment: Are you sure you're not using build tools?  Rails 4 uses the asset pipeline by default, which is a build tool.  Can you post the full list of `<script>` tags on your page in the order that they appear in your app after rendering?

Comment: @jeremy thanks for taking a look. I have added the full list script tag that appears after rendering to the bottom of my question, as it is too long to add to this comment section. I don't think I added any builds tool beside the default sprockets or asset-pipeline that comes with rails, no other build tool is in my rails application manifest and I created all emberjs files and folders manually without using any sort of generator. I don't use the generators provided by ember-rails. The only external javascript in library or framework in my app for now are jquery, emberjs and ember-data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have `ember-rails` in your `Gemfile` you're probably getting the version of Ember that it provides, not the one that lives in `app/assets/javascripts/lib/development`.  You can load `/assets/ember.js` in your browser to verify.  If you want to make sure you get your custom version you should use this in `application.js`

```
//= require lib/development/ember
```

Alternatively to be extra sure, you could remove ember from `application.js` completely and include the latest canary ember directly in your layout.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="http://builds.emberjs.com/canary/ember.js"></script>
```

[UPDATE] : OK, the problem is that you're including ember.js multiple times (and possibly with multiple versions).  I missed it when you first posted your bit list of script tags, but if you look at that closely you'll see that Ember and Ember Data are included at the top (lines 4 and 5 of the scripts), and then they're each included two mored times at the bottom.

```
...
<script src="/assets/ember.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/ember-data.js?body=1"></script>
...
<script src="/assets/lib/development/ember-data.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/lib/development/ember.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/lib/production/ember-data.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/lib/production/ember.js?body=1"></script>
...
```

My guess is that `application.js` is requiring ember once on purpose with

```
//= require ember
```

And then it's getting picked up again with a `require_tree`

```
//= require_tree .
```

Usually you want to store external libraries (code that you do not personally maintain) in the `vendor` directory of your app.  This would allow to still use `require_tree` to get all of your own javascript included in one shot.  In my project that uses `ember-rails` my structure looks like this:

```
app
  assets
    javascripts
      # All my own stuff goes here
vendor
  assets
    ember
      development
        ember.js
        ember-data.js
      production
        ember.js
        ember-data.js
```

`ember-rails` will find the versions in `vendor` if you just use `require ember` in `application.js`.  You'll want to make sure that you set `config.ember.variant` in each of your `config/environments/*.rb` files.  For instance in `config/environments/development.rb` you'll need to add this :

```
config.ember.variant = :development
```

Comment: Thanks Jeremy I have switched between using **//= require ember** and **//= require ./lib/development/ember**  and doing same-thing for ember-data. The original error is still occurring but in addition, when I use the **//= ./lib/development/ember/** it throws some additional errors shown here **http://i.imgur.com/3ToLsUW.png**. Errors like **Assertion failed: The initializer 'store' has already been registered**. Assertion failed: The initializer 'transforms' has already been registered. **Assertion failed: The initializer 'dataAdapter' has already been registered**

Comment: OK, see the [UPDATE] I just added to my original answer.

Comment: Thanks for the time you have spent helping. About 2 hours ago  I moved it to **vendor** assets as you described above and because I am on Rails 4, it was being picked up automatically, I spent some time reading the various suggestions on how to make assets files in **vendor** to be picked up automatically, none worked, so I moved them back to **javascripts/lib**.

Comment: Thanks for helping. I finally got it working following your updated answer.